# Django and bidirectional relationship between model

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I need to store some relationship type data between a set of objects (let's call them Person's). So, some models like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Relationship(models.Model)
    person1 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person1')
    person2 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person2')
    relationship_type = models.ChoiceField(choices=...)
    information = models.TextField()
```

... So, each Person can be linked to any other Person. However, some of the relationships are not *directional*, so it doesn't matter who is person1 or who is person2 (with this example let's say PersonA is a "friend" of PersonB). Other types of relationships are *directional* where the ordering does matter (say, e.g. PersonC is "the boss of" PersonD).

What's the best way to handle this in Django?

Comment: Have you tried manytomanyfields?

Comment: How many rows will person have? What is your database backend? What kind of queries will you perform about directional and not directional models? You will be mix results for directional and not directional models?

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution would be to have a two models for relationships between users. 
One is for *directional* and one for *bidirectional*
Think about logic your program. Almost every time you fetch a user from database you need to know what kind of relationship is it. With two Relationship models you will not have such a problem. Only tradeoff of this way is that you have to make two queries to show all relations between persons - but in most cases this is not so often task.